# How do I test Kotlin coroutines inside a function?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am creating a library and I'm using Retrofit with a call-adapter that gives me a Deferred<> value.

In a function in my code I call `launch {}`, and inside that i `try-catch` the values, and possible exceptions - calling different callbacks for different results.

The resources I've found on testing coroutines are all about testing suspended functions, and `runBlocking {}` is the solution to everything. Except for me it isn't

I made a quick example

```
    @Mock
val mockListener: DoSomething.Listener = mock()

@Test
fun testSomething() {
    val doer = DoSomething(mockListener)
    runBlocking {
        doer.doIt()
        verify(mockListener).listen(any())
    }
}

class DoSomething(val listener: Listener) {

    interface Listener {
        fun listen(s: String)
    }

    fun doIt() {
        launch {
            listener.listen(theThing().await())
        }
    }

    private fun theThing(): Deferred<String> {
        return async {
            delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            return@async "Wow, a thing"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is for the actually run all functions. The test should take 5 seconds minimum, but it just runs through the code in a couple of millisconds- ie. it doesn't block.

I've tried adding

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        // doer.doIt()
    }.joinChildren()
}
```

And similar practices but I just can't get the test to actually wait for my launch inside of another class to finish before the test is finished.
Placing the `verify(...)` outside of the `runBlocking` also makes the test fail, which it should.

Any input, helpers, good practice etc. is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the CoroutineContext explicitly for your `doIt()` function:

```
fun doIt(context: CoroutineContext = DefaultDispatcher) {
    launch(context) {
        listener.listen(theThing().await()
    }
}
```

With this parameter you could easily change the coroutine context - in your test code you use the blocking context:

```
runBlocking {
    doer.doIt(coroutineContext)
}
```

BTW: You don't need to use `launch` and `async`. With `launch` you are in a `suspendable` context and you don't need to run `theThing()` asynchronously. Especially if you invoke `await()` in the next step:

```
fun doIt(context: CoroutineContext = DefaultDispatcher) {
    launch(context) {
        listener.listen(theThing())
    }
}

private suspend fun theThing(): String {
    delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return "Wow, a thing"
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you! I shouldn't of course wrap the functionality in a launch, I should make the function suspend and `launch` the function. That's how you make it testable.
(I don't agree with sending in the `coroutineContext`, that's seems kind'a weird. But `suspend` is definitely the way to go for testability!

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be not to swallow `Job` in your `doIt()` function as you do now.
Instead of

```
fun doIt() {
    launch {
        listener.listen(theThing().await())
    }
}
```

Do

```
fun doIt() = launch {
        listener.listen(theThing().await())
    }
```

That way your function will return a coroutine, which you can wait for:

```
doIt().join()
```

Better still is to use `async()` instead of `launch()`

Another comment is that `doIt()` should be actually `doItAsync()`, as suggested by Kotlin guidelines.